# Python type hints and `*args`

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, pycharm, type-hinting

Assume I have a function like this:

```
def foo(*args):
    for x in args:
        print(x)
```

and let's say I want to say that all the elements of `args` are `int`; what is the right way to express it as of [PEP 0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)? Should I do something like

```
from typing import Tuple


def foo(*args: Tuple[int, ...]) -> None:
    for x in args:
        print(x)
```

or something like

```
def foo(*args: int) -> None:
    for x in args:
        print(x)
```

or something else entirely?

In particular, I'm trying to use type hints effectively in PyCharm, and none of the solutions I've thought of seems to help PyCharm understand that `x` should be an `int`.

Comment: Your first approach is correct, use `Tuple[int, ..]`, `*args: int` will always be wrong since Python will create a tuple for `*args` with the excess positional values passed.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard It appears `*args` and `**kwargs` are special-cased by [PEP 0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), as per the now-accepted answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values):

> Arbitrary argument lists can as well be type annotated, so that the definition:
>
> ```
> def foo(*args: str, **kwds: int): ...
> ```
>
> is acceptable and it means that, e.g., all of the following represent function calls with valid types of arguments:
>
> ```
> foo('a', 'b', 'c')
> foo(x=1, y=2)
> foo('', z=0)
> ```
>
> In the body of function `foo`, the type of variable `args` is deduced as `Tuple[str, ...]` and the type of variable `kwds` is `Dict[str, int]`.

The correct way to annotate the `foo` function from your example is:

```
def foo(*args: int) -> None:
    for x in args:
        print(x)
```

In Python 2:

```
def foo(*args):
    # type: (*int) -> None
    for x in args:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the docstrings. PyCharm allows you to define your arguments in docstrings, with or without the types. If you define the types, the hints will take into consideration the type of the arguments.

```
def foo(*args):
    """
    General information about foo
    :param [int] args: info about args
    """

    for x in args:
        print(x)
```

Comment: Great, as a quick fix it seems to work. I'd still prefer a solution based on type hints with function annotations, but if nothing comes out I'll settle with this